# why the rerun failed jobs did not work in github actions

Tags: github-actions

When I run the github actions, I found the last step failed. Now I only want to rerun the last step, then I choose the `rerun failed jobs`. but the github actions still rerun the full jobs, is it possible to let github actions only run the failed jobs? choose jobs type like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Github docs for rerunning jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/re-running-workflows-and-jobs) says the following:

> If any jobs in a workflow run failed, you can re-run just the jobs that failed. When you re-run failed jobs in a workflow, a new workflow run will start for all failed jobs and their dependents. Any outputs for any successful jobs in the previous workflow run will be used for the re-run.

Hence, you can rerun only failed jobs by choosing `Re-run failed jobs` and it will only run the failed jobs, but those jobs will be run fully and not only some particular step.